# How to get child under sub-category and sub-category user category in JSON Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, loops, laravel-5

This very common question but I am not able to make it in JSON Format for API. I a Table **Category** where I stored three layers of Category. Category->subcategory->child.
I want to get this in API in Format.

Something like.

```
Category

  sub-category-1
  sub-category-2 
      child-2-1
      child-2-2
  sub-category-3
```

I try with code

```
  $allData = array();
            // get all parent category 
            $categories = Category::where(['status' => 1, 'parent_id' => 0])->get();        
            foreach ($categories as $key=>$sub) {
                    // now take one by one it's child category 
                    $allData[$key]['parent'] = $sub->name;
                    $subCategory = Category::where('status', 1)->where('parent_id', '=', $sub->id)->get();
                    $subCat = array();
                    // set parent category title
                    foreach ($subCategory as $k=>$subcat) {
                        $subCat[$subcat->id] = $subcat->name;

                    }
                    // set subcategory array
                    $allData[$key]['subcategory'] = $subCat;
            }
           return $allData;
```

**I got this result not I don't know how to get child value**

[image]

**database look like**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I solved this

```
       $parents = Category::where('parent_id', 0)->where('status', 1)->orderBy('sort_order', 'asc')->get();
        foreach ($parents as $parent) {
            $childs = Category::where('parent_id', $parent->id)->where('status', 1)->orderBy('sort_order', 'asc')->get();
            if (count($childs) > 0) {
                $subCat = array();
                $players = array();
                $roster[$parent->name] = $players;
                        foreach ($childs as $i => $child) {
                            $subchilds = Category::where('parent_id', $child->id)->where('status', 1)->orderBy('sort_order', 'asc')->get();
                            if (count($subchilds) > 0) {

                                $roster[$parent->name][$child->name] = $subCat;
                                foreach ($subchilds as $subchild) {

                                    $roster[$parent->name][$child->name][$subchild->id] = $subchild->name;
                                }

                            }else{
                                $roster[$parent->name][$child->name] = $players;
                            }
                        }

            }
        }
        return $roster;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it.

```
 $allData = array();
        // get all parent category 
        $categories = Category::where(['status' => 1, 'parent_id' => 0])->get();        
        foreach ($categories as $key=>$sub) {
                // now take one by one it's child category 
                $allData[$key]['parent'] = $sub->name;
                $subCategory = Category::where('status', 1)->where('parent_id', '=', $sub->id)->get();
                $subCat = array();
                // set parent category title
                foreach ($subCategory as $k=>$subcat) {
                    $subCat[$subcat->id] = $subcat->name;
                    //children of subcat 
                    $children = Category::where('status', 1)->where('parent_id', '=', $subcat->id)->get();  
                    $child = array();
                    if($children){
                        foreach($children as $k1=>$val){
                             $child[$val->id] = $val->name;
                             $allData[$key]['subcategory'][$subcat->id]['child'] = $child;
                        }
                    }

                }
                // set subcategory array
                $allData[$key]['subcategory'] = $subCat;
        }
       return $allData;
```

please try this way. convert your json into array and use this to get child values

```
$ar = json_decode($data,true);
foreach($ar as $value){
    echo $value['parent'].'<br>';
    foreach($value['child'] as $child){

       echo '&nbsp;'.$child.'<br>';
   }
 }
```

This will output this

```
test
 A
 B
 C
 D
 E
test1
 G
 H
 I
 J
 K
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer but I want also the child of sub-categories

Comment: what is your current array look like ?

Comment: In Question i mention a image of Current result.

Comment: you added parent and child only, parent is categoary and child is sub sub category. where are subcategories ?

Comment: Yes, I want to get a child that is my question on how to get a child's of subcategory

Comment: how your database  table looks like ?

Comment: Update Question

Comment: I think you are very close to the solution your code gives this result.  https://i.imgur.com/w0VEz65.png

Comment: The child "Tablets" is a child of mobile so it should come under mobile

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205295/discussion-between-amit-sharma-and-brij-sharma).

Comment: Thanks for the upvote could you please mark this as answer if it helps you a little